# Listings applies keywording where it shouldn't

Tags: listings

I want to implement Python code inside a LaTeX file. A minimalistic example follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\scriptsize,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
otherkeywords={self,with,as},
keywordstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
emph={MyClass,__init__,In,Out},
emphstyle=\color{red}
showstringspaces=false,
}}

{\pythonstyle\begin{lstlisting}
# with my current listing, this is not working as inteded

import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame()
\end{lstlisting}}


\end{document}
```

producing the following output

[image: Tex file output]

What can I do that the keywordstyle is only applied to whole words and not for every case tex finds, even inside some words?

Comment: +1: Interesting question and nice MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deeper look into the documentation of listings revealed that I'm using the wrong options. It says, that ([source](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)):

> [...]
>
> otherkeywords={〈keywords〉}
>
> > Defines keywords that contain other
> >     characters, or start with digits.  Eachgiven ‘keyword’ is printed in
> >     keyword style, but without changing the ‘letter’,‘digit’ and ‘other’
> >     status of the characters.  This key is designed to definekeywords
> >     like=>,->,-->,--,::, and so on.  If one keyword is a subsequenceof
> >     another (like--and-->), you must specify the shorter first.
>
> [...]

The appropriate option was `morekeywords`. Using `morekeywords`, instead of `otherkeywords`, solved my problem! @Dr.ManuelKuehner, this should be interesting for you! @TeXnician, thanks for your alternitive solution although!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\scriptsize,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
morekeywords={self,with,as},
keywordstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
emph={MyClass,__init__,In,Out},
emphstyle=\color{red}
showstringspaces=false,
}}

{\pythonstyle\begin{lstlisting}
# with my current listing, this is not working as inteded

import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame()
\end{lstlisting}}


\end{document}
```

[image: Correct result]

Thanks again!
Best wishes

Answer (score 4):

Just as an alternative: `minted` does quite a good job at highlighting only what is needed.

[image: minted example]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usemintedstyle{vs}
\setminted{bgcolor=GhostWhite!90!gray}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
# with my current listing, this is not working as inteded

import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame()
\end{minted}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Do you also have a solution regarding the `listings` package? First I thought, this must be a common problem, but I failed to find a duplicate.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner No, I do not have one. A simple way would be to use `\ as` as keyword specification, but that will not solve wrong comment highlighting.